# How i can call my custom class's method inside @PostFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Student> {

    @Override
    @PostFilter("myClass.MyMethod(filterObject, HttpServletRequest)")
    Iterable<Student> findAll(Predicate predicate);
}
```

I want to use **@PostFilter("myClass.MyMethod(filterObject, HttpServletRequest)")** in my code. Also Please tell me the way to enable it properly.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a suitable solution? I am in a similar situation. I want to extend the principal object which is made available in the `@Postfilter` annotation's context and although I was able to figure out how to create my own object which extended Boots UserDetails object I could not figure out how to swap them during `@Postfilter`

Comment: @PhillipStack, i actually handle that situation by HttpInterceptor https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm. The way i implemented it is: I capture the requested URL and append my filter in that URL and redirect current request to newly created URL (just add some logic to not include same filter again when redirecting because interceptor logic will be call for each request).